# How to execute a second condition if the first condition is true in Linux shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, script

I have an `if` condition. If that condition is true then one script will be run and after that I need to check another condition.

How can I do that using an `if` statement or something else?

For example,

```
 if [ condition -eq o ]
 then
 run script
 again condition(this condition depends on above script output value)
 run another script
 else
 exit
```

Answer (score 6):

#### How to execute second condition if first condition true

Your code needs to have the following structure:

```
if [condition -ne 0]
then 
  do_something 
  if [expression that depends on exit status of do_something]
  then 
    do something_else 
  fi 
fi
```

---

> **SYNTAX**
>
> ```
> if test-commands; then
>   consequent-commands;
> [elif more-test-commands; then
>    more-consequents;]
> [else alternate-consequents;]
> fi
> ```
>
> The `test-commands` list is executed, and if its return status is
>   zero, the `consequent-commands` list is executed.
>
> If `test-commands` returns a non-zero status, each elif list is
>   executed in turn, and if its exit status is zero, the corresponding
>   `more-consequents` is executed and the command completes.
>
> If `else alternate-consequents` is present, and the final command in
>   the final if or elif clause has a non-zero exit status, then
>   `alternate-consequents` is executed.
>
> The return status is the exit status of the last command executed, or
>   zero if no condition tested true.

See below for a link with examples.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Bash command line for Linux](http://ss64.com/bash/) - An excellent reference for all things Bash command line related.
- [Conditional Expressions](http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-condition.html) - Conditional expressions are used by bracketed expressions and the test builtin.
- [if](http://ss64.com/bash/if.html) - Conditionally perform a command.
- [Bash If Statement Examples (If then fi, If then else fi, If elif else fi, Nested if)](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-if-statement-examples/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but my point is that , if first condition returns zero status then i need run other condition ,if first condition returns non zero value then no need of executing other commands/conditions.

Comment: @bunny Use `-ne` instead of `-eq` See [Conditional Expressions](http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-condition.html) - Conditional expressions are used by bracketed expressions and the test builtin.

Comment: Any suggesstions from anyone ?

Comment: @bunny I alread told you what you need to do. Use -ne instead of -eq in the first `if` expression. Please spend some time reading the links I gave in the answer section "Further reading". We cannot write the code for you as you have only written psuedo-code not real code.

Comment: @bunny Answer updated. The rest is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like

```
first-condition && consequences1
```

Followed by:

(again)

```
first-condition && second-condition && consequences2
```

This may be changed to `if;then;fi` by inserting a secondary `if` into the original:

```
if [ first-condition ]; then
   consequences1
   if [ second-condition ]; then # Because first-condition is already true here
      consequences2
   fi
fi
```

So your `consequences2` is NOT an "else" issue at all :) Nesting is fun.

If your second-condition is simply based on the output of consequences1, you can run that in the test of the second `if`:

```
if [ first-condition ]; then
  if [ consequences1-test ]; then
    consequences2
  fi
 fi
```

It should [sweeten your pot](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sweeten_the_pot). Just recall that ANYTHING can be run in a test; only the returncode of the last command (or the output on stdio), but you'll need to test something then: like

```
[ "`consequences1`" == "allok" ]
```

matters

Comment: Suggestion: Avoid 'backticks' and use `$(...)` instead, for clarity. :-)

Comment: Below is my script .Please check.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> cd lock
> if [ $(ls -ltr | grep -q exitup) -eq 0 ]; then
> rm exitup
> if [ $(Appl_Monitor | echo $?) -ne 110 ]; then
> kb_shutdown
> kb_startup
> if [ $(ls -ltr | grep -q exitup) - eq 0 ]; then
> rm exitup
> if [ $(Appl_Monitor | echo $?) -eq 110 ]; then
> echo " kb app is fine
>        $(ls -ltr | Appli_Monitor | echo $?) | mailx -s "KB App " abc@gmail.com
> else
> echo " Warning KB app is not running
>        $(ls -ltr | Appli_Monitor | echo $?) | mailx -s "KB App " abc@gmail.com
> fi
> fi
> fi
> fi
> ```

With my knowledge i made this script. If any mistakes ,give suggestions.
where kb_startup ,kb_shutdown and appl_monitor are programs which are defiend in /bin